# "Будьте ответственны" или "будьте ответственными"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика, прилагательные

У меня сложилось впечатление, что если речь идёт о качестве человека, то всегда должен быть творительный падеж. Однако же фраза "они будут ответственны за всевозможные последствия" тоже имеет право на существование.

Правильно ли что:

1. "Будьте ответственными" (какими) — творительный падеж и в данным случае прилагательное.
2. "Будьте ответственны" (за кого-то) — именительный падеж и в данное случае это причастие

Answer (score 2):

***Ответственный*** – полная форма прилагательного, ***ответственен, ответственны*** – краткая форма прилагательного (здесь разные формы, а не падежи).

**Различение кратких и полных форм делается по многим признакам**, это довольно большая по объему тема. Иногда формы имеют разное значение, в других случаях могут заменять друг друга.

Роезенталь  http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/58.htm

**Основные различия**

1) Полные формы обычно обозначают **постоянный признак,** вневременное качество, а краткие – **временный признак**, ср.: мать больная – мать больна; 
Это положение не имеет категорического характера.

2) В других случаях полная форма обозначает **абсолютный признак**, не связанный с конкретной обстановкой, а краткая – **относительный признак**, применительно к определенной ситуации.  Ср.: потолок низкий (признак вообще) – потолок низок (для высокой мебели);

3) Стилистическое различие между обеими формами выражается в том, что для краткой формы характерен оттенок **категоричности**, для полной – оттенок **смягченного выражения.** Ср.: он хитер – он хитрый, она смела – она смелая и т.п.

4) Краткая форма нередко присуща **книжному языку**, полная – **разговорному**.

***Будьте ответственными.*** Обычно речь идет о  характере человека (абсолютный признак), но: ***будьте ответственны*** за свои поступки (указывается конкретная тема).

**Примечание.** Краткая форма используется чаще, так как имеет не только прямой, но и переносный смысл, например: лейкоциты **ответственны** за иммунно-защитную функцию организма.

**Примеры:**

***Будьте ответственными.***  Управление автомобилем – это всегда большая ответственность и определенный риск.

***Будьте ответственны*** за свои слова и поступки. ***Будьте ответственны*** за того, кого вы приручили.